# Gap in table TRs *CSS/HTML*

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, html-table

I have two rows in my table that have random gaps beneath them. I have tried looking at colspans and messing around for ages, but they just don't seem to go.  I have 3 `<th>`'s as you can see, and tried to align the rest of the table with this.  The table is complete, and looks okay except for the blank lines beneath the rows with "timeleft" and "reward".

```
     <table class="tabelle separate">
        <tr>
        <th>Jail</th><th></th><th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td width="40%"><div class="zelle"><center><b>Inmate</div></td>
    <td width="25%"><div class="zelle"><center><b>Time left</div></td>
    <td width="35%"><div class="zelle"><center><b>Reward</div></td>
    </tr>

    <?php

//desplay data

$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jail");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
//get data
$id = $row['id'];
$name = ucwords($row['username']);
$timeleft = $row['time'] - time();
$reward = number_format($row['reward']);
$jailedcountry = $row['country'];

if($country === $jailedcountry){

echo "
<tr>


<td width=40%><div class='zelle'>
<form action='jail.php' method='post'>
<input name='bustid' type='radio' class='radio' value='$id'><a href='viewprofile.php?viewuser=$name'>
$name</a></div></td>


<td width=25%><div class='zelle'>$timeleft
</div></td>

<td width=35%><div class='zelle'>
$$reward</div></td>

</tr>
";


}


echo "
<tr><br><br>
<td align='center' colspan='3'><div class='zelle'>
<center> <input type='submit' name='bust' class='tbox' value='Bust User'> <Br>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
";
}

?>


<tr><td colspan="3"><div class="zelle">
<form action='jail.php' method='post'><center><input type='submit' name='pointsleave' class='tbox' value='Leave Jail (Costs 2 points)'> </center></form>
</div></td></tr>
</table>

CSS
.tabelle {
    width: 50%; border-collapse: collapse;  margin: auto; border-right: 1px solid Black;
}
.zelle{
    padding: 1px; 
    background-color: #202020; 
    font-family: Arial; 
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center; 
    color: white; 
}

th {
 background: #696969;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #696969, #393b3d);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #696969, #393b3d);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #696969, #393b3d);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #696969, #393b3d);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #696969, #393b3d);
    padding: 6px; 
    color: White; 
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial; 
}
.separate {
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: separate;

}
.separate tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.separate tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
.separate tr th:first-child, table.separate tr td:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid Black;
}
.separate tr:first-child th, table.separate tr:first-child td {
    border-top: 1px solid Black;
}
.separate tr:first-child th:first-child, table.separate tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 3px
}
.separate tr:first-child th:last-child, table.separate tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;   
}
```

Comment: It is better to use flex-box instead of table for layout

Comment: Post the rendered HTML please; not the PHP. Also don't use the `<center>` tag

Comment: Either remove the class `. separate` or change that class property `border-collapse` to `collapse` Or counter adjust those borders with negative padding.